# R: match a vector in another vector as a whole

Tags: r

Is there an easy, straightforward way (possibly a builtin function) that could match one vector as a whole in another vector?
Example:

```
target <- c(1,2,3)
A <- c(4,5,6,1,2,3)
B <- c(4,5,6,3,2,1)

my_match(target, A) # TRUE
my_match(target, B) # FALSE
```

I tried `%in%`, `match` and `pmatch` but these won't give the desired result. For example, both `target %in% A` and `target %in% B` will give the result `[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE`, which is not what I want.

Comment: You could use some of the info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33418495/how-do-i-return-the-row-index-of-a-sequence-in-r/33419512#33419512).  All you'd need to do is adjust the function to return true or false for length == 0

Comment: @RichardScriven Thank you for pointing me to the related question. I guess this is a duplicate after all. It's just that so many people describe the same problem differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here another version

```
multi_match=function(target,A) {
  lA=length(A)
  lt=length(target)
  if (lt>lA) return(FALSE)
  any(colSums(sapply(1:(lA-lt+1),function(i) A[i:(i+lt-1)])==target)==lt)
}
```

Let's try it with some data

```
target <- c(1,2,3)
A <- c(4,5,6,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,3)
B <- c(4,5,6,3,2,1)

multi_match(target,A)
#TRUE

multi_match(target,B)
#FALSE

#"wrong" input order - trivially no match
multi_match(A,target)
#FALSE
```

And an extension of the `multi_match` function above to `multi_which`.

```
multi_which=function(target,A) {
  lA=length(A)
  lt=length(target)
  if (lt>lA) return(integer(0))
  which(colSums(sapply(1:(lA-lt+1),function(i) A[i:(i+lt-1)])==target)==lt)
}


multi_which(target,A)
#[1] 4 7

multi_which(target,B)
#integer(0)

#"wrong" input order - trivially no match
multi_which(A,target)
#integer(0)
```

Comment: Thanks cryo111. Actually your answer is basically what I have written myself(not posted here). I am just baffled that I cannot find a builtin way to do this. And thanks @PierreLafortune for pointing out the bug in Roman's answer.

Comment: @Benny Apart from R and C++, I do not know/use many other programming languages. Do you know whether there are built-in functions like that in Matlab/Mathematica/Python/...?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
grepl(paste(target,collapse=","),paste(A,collapse=","))
grepl(paste(target,collapse=","),paste(B,collapse=","))
```

This concatenates the vectors into strings and looks for a substring in the second argument that matches the first.

You could put this into a function that returns true or false:

```
my_match <- function(x,y,dlm=",") grepl(paste(x,collapse=dlm),paste(y,collapse=dlm))

my_match(target,A)
[1] TRUE
my_match(target,B)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Pretty cool solution. Minor note, why not just use `grepl` instead of `length(grep) > 0`?

Comment: @RomanTsegelskyi Good point.  I wasn't thinking.  I've updated it.

Comment: Thanks sam, and I admit that in general this will work, but basically this is a hack and in (not so common but yet still possible) cases such that `target<-c("a,b","c"); A<-c("a","b","c")`, `my_match` will falsely give out `TRUE`.

Comment: True.  In that case, adding a delimiter to the function would allow a workaround. As updated.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is to use `match` and check if resulting sequence is rising

```
all(diff(match(target, A)) == 1) && length(match(target, A)) == length(target)
```

Or as a function

```
> exact_match <- function(p, x) all(diff(match(p, x)) == 1) && length(match(p, x)) == length(p)
> exact_match(target,A)
[1] TRUE
> exact_match(target,B)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: This looks great! Thanks Roman, I prefer your answer. I wonder why R does not have a built-in function for this.

Comment: Yeah that is surprising. When I saw the question, I was looking for some built-in way too and to my surprise there was nothing obvious. Maybe I was missing something, but apparently there is not default way to check for subsequence.

Comment: This might look good but it is more fragile than the other answer. This solution fails if there is a repeat. The other answer doesn't. Try `A <- c(1,1,2,3)`