# Match a sequence of elements to a longer vector with some similar sequences

Tags: r

How can I count the number of times the specific sequence of elements x exists in the longer vector y.

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
y <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,3,2,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,9,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4)
```

Sorry but could not come out with any way to do it as using match will match individual elements but not a string or sequence of elements.

Comment: You are looking to match a sequence or specific numbers? It's not clear what's your desired output? I would think you are looking for something like `stringi::stri_count_fixed(paste(y, collapse = ""), paste(x, collapse = ""))`

Comment: Wrap [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33418495/how-do-i-return-the-row-index-of-a-sequence-in-r/33419512#33419512) with `length()` and you have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to add to the current answer and Davids comment,

```
    length(gregexpr(paste(x,collapse = ""), paste(y, collapse=""))[[1L]])
```

fails in the general case. This is because if there are no matches, the resultant index is -1, giving a length of 1, rather than correct answer 0.

```
    x = c(1,2,3)
    y = c(4,3,2,4,3,4,3,2,2,3)
    length(gregexpr(paste(x,collapse = ""), paste(y, collapse=""))[[1L]])
    # [1] 1
```

whereas `stringi::stri_count_fixed` returns the expected 0.

A different answer which does not rely on pasting to strings should you prefer it, I suspect that it is slower however:

```
    library(zoo)
    sum(rollapply(y, width = length(x), function(v) all(x == v)))
```

Comment: The last one could be written: `sum(rollapply(y, length(x), identical, x))`

Comment: Bah, missed that, well spotted

Answer (score 1):

```
cy <- paste(y, collapse = "")
cx <- paste(x, collapse = "")
(nchar(cy) - nchar(gsub(cx, "", cy))) / nchar(cx)
[1] 4
```

This is also robust to the case mentioned by @jamieRowen when the expected result is 0.