# See which vector in a list is contained within a vector from another list (finding people's name matches)

Tags: r, list, match, sapply

I have one list of vectors of people's names, where each vector just has the first and last name and I have another list of vectors, where each vector has the first, middle, last names. I need to match the two lists to find people who are included in both lists. Because the names are not in order (some vectors have the first name as the first value, while others have the last name as the first value), I would like to match the two vectors by finding which vector in the second list (full name) contains all the values of a vector in the first list (first and last names only).

What I have done so far:

```
#reproducible example
first_last_names_list <- list(c("boy", "boy"),
                       c("bob", "orengo"),
                       c("kalonzo", "musyoka"),
                       c("anami", "lisamula"))

full_names_list <- list(c("boy", "juma", "boy"), 
                        c("stephen", "kalonzo", "musyoka"),
                        c("james", "bob", "orengo"),
                        c("lisamula", "silverse", "anami"))
```

First, I tried to make a function that checks whether one vector is contained in another vector (heavily based on the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34445106/test-if-vector-is-contained-in-another-vector-including-repetitions)).

```
my_contain <- function(values,x){
    tx <- table(x)
    tv <- table(values)
    z <- tv[names(tx)] - tx
    if(all(z >= 0 & !is.na(z))){
       paste(x, collapse = " ")
       }
    }

#value would be the longer vector (from full_name_list) 
#and x would be the shorter vector(from first_last_name_list)
```

Then, I tried to put this function within sapply() so that I can work with lists and that's where I got stuck. I can get it to see whether one vector is contained within a list of vectors, but I'm not sure how to check all the vectors in one list and see if it is contained within any of the vectors from a second list.

```
#testing with the first vector from first_last_names_list. 
#Need to make it run through all the vectors from first_last_names_list.

sapply(1:length(full_names_list),
   function(i) any(my_contain(full_names_list[[i]], 
                              first_last_names_list[[1]]) == 
                              paste(first_last_names_list[[1]], collapse = " ")))

#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Lastly- although it might be too much to ask in one question- if anyone could give me any pointers on how to incorporate agrep() for fuzzy matching to account for typos in the names, that would be great! If not, that's okay too, since I want to get at least the matching part right first.

Comment: Wewe wajua Kiswahili? Hayo majina nayajua.

Comment: @Onyambu Ndiyo, lakini najua kidogo. Wakati uliopita, niliishi Nairobi. Sasa nimesahau maneno mengi...

Comment: You just spoke fluently.. its okay.. i did answer your question. Only that i did not understand what exactly you wanted to be matched

Comment: If you know any company/ organization that has statistical work to be done, eg data analysis, mining etc, you can give them my contacts

Comment: @Onyambu Yes, it did. I've picked your answer as the most helpful since I can easily modify it to use agrep for fuzzy matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are dealing with `lists` it would be better to collapse them into vectors to be easy to deal with regular expressions. But you just arrange them in ascending order. In that case you can easily match them:

```
lst=sapply(first_last_names_list,function(x)paste0(sort(x),collapse=" "))
 lst1=gsub("\\s|$",".*",lst)
 lst2=sapply(full_names_list,function(x)paste(sort(x),collapse=" "))
 (lst3 = Vectorize(grep)(lst1,list(lst2),value=T,ignore.case=T))
               boy.*boy.*             bob.*orengo.*        kalonzo.*musyoka.*         anami.*lisamula.* 
           "boy boy juma"        "bob james orengo" "kalonzo musyoka stephen" "anami lisamula silverse"
```

Now if you want to link `first_name_last_name_list` and `full_name_list` then:

```
setNames(full_names_list[ match(lst3,lst2)],sapply(first_last_names_list[grep(paste0(names(lst3),collapse = "|"),lst1)],paste,collapse=" "))
$`boy boy`
[1] "boy"  "juma" "boy" 

$`bob orengo`
[1] "james"  "bob"    "orengo"

$`kalonzo musyoka`
[1] "stephen" "kalonzo" "musyoka"

$`anami lisamula`
[1] "lisamula" "silverse" "anami"
```

where the names are from first_last_list and the elements are full_name_list. It would be great for you to deal with character vectors rather than lists:

Answer (score 1):

***Edit*** I've modified the solution to satisfy the constraint that a repeated name such as 'John John' should not match against 'John Smith'.

```
apply(sapply(first_last_names_list, unlist), 2, function(x){
        any(sapply(full_names_list, function(y) sum(unlist(y) %in% x) >= length(x)))
    })
```

This solution still uses `%in%` and the apply functions, but it now does a kind of reverse search - for every element in the `first_last` names it looks at 
*how many words* in each name within the `full_names` list are matched. If this number is *greater than or equal to* the number of words in the `first_list` names item under consideration (always 2 words in your examples, but the code will work for any number), it returns TRUE. This logical array is then aggregated with `ANY` to pass back single vector showing if each first_last is matched to any full_name.

So for example, 'John John' *would not* be matched to 'John Smith Random', as only 1 of the 3 words in 'John Smith Random' are matched. However, it *would be* matched to 'John Adam John', as 2 of the 3 words in 'John Adam John' are matched, and 2 is equal to the length of 'John John'. It would also match to 'John John John John John' as 5 of the 5 words match, which is greater than 2.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. I do not want "John John" to be matched with "John Smith," which is why I cannot use %in%. 

However, this gives me an idea- maybe I can first go through the names and append some suffix to any repetition found in a person's name. (ex- turn "John John" into "John John1"). This way I think I will be able to catch the repetitions as well.

Comment: @SaewonPark understood now. I've edited solution to one which will work under this constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of my_contain, try

```
x %in% values
```

Maybe also unlist and work with data frames? Not sure if you considered it--might make things easier:

```
# unlist to vectors
fl <- unlist(first_last_names_list)
fn <- unlist(full_names_list)

# grab individual names and convert to dfs; 
# assumptions: first_last_names_list only contains 2-element vectors
#              full_names_list only contains 3-element vectors
first_last_df <- data.frame(first_fl=fl[c(T, F)],last_fl=fl[c(F, T)])
full_name_df <- data.frame(first_fn=fn[c(T,F,F)],mid_fn=fn[c(F,T,F)],last_fn=fn[c(F,F,T)])
```

Comment: Thank you. The reason I did not use %in% was because it does not take repetition into account. There are some people who have the same first and last name and I would like to find a match with a vector that also contains the repetition (ex- John John would match with John Smith, although they shouldn't).  Could you explain why data frames may be more beneficial?

Comment: I see. If you are using dfs you could check each name from the first against each name from the second set (not perfect):
`# find row numbers that have either the first name or the last name`  
`match1 <- sapply(first_last_df$first,function(x){match(x,full_name_df$first)})`  
`match2 <- sapply(first_last_df$last,function(x){match(x,full_name_df$last)})` `match3 <- sapply(first_last_df$first,function(x){match(x,full_name_df$last)})`  `match4 <- sapply(first_last_df$last,function(x){match(x,full_name_df$first)})`  `first_last_df[!is.na(match1==match2 | match3==match4),]`

Comment: Sorry, completely butchered the formatting here. The main point is that the match vectors give you the row indices of each name's match within the data frame. match1 and 2 assume that the first and last name are properly stored in each data frame, match3 and 4 switch it around. The row selector in the last line checks if these indices for 1 and 2 or 3 and 4 are the same, i.e. if the first and the last name have been found within the same row(s) of the data frame, which would mean that they're in both lists.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do this:

```
first_last_names_list <- list(c("boy", "boy"),
                          c("bob", "orengo"),
                          c("kalonzo", "musyoka"),
                          c("anami", "lisamula")) 

full_names_list <- list(c("boy", "juma", "boy"), 
                    c("stephen", "kalonzo", "musyoka"),
                    c("james", "bob", "orengo"),
                    c("lisamula", "silverse", "anami"),
                    c("musyoka", "jeremy", "kalonzo")) # added just to test

# create copies of full_names_list without middle name; 
# one list with matching name order, one with inverted order
full_names_short <- lapply(full_names_list,function(x){x[c(1,3)]})
full_names_inv <- lapply(full_names_list,function(x){x[c(3,1)]})

# check if names in full_names_list match either
full_names_list[full_names_short %in% first_last_names_list | full_names_inv %in% first_last_names_list]
```

In this case `%in%` does exactly what you want it to do, it checks if the complete name vector matches.

Comment: Thanks again. This is similar to the way I was going to it if I failed to find a more elegant way to do it. The actual code would be longer than this, because some people's middle names are switched with either their first name or last name and so I cannot delete the middle names. I would permute to get all the combinations for the three names (basically P(3,2)).