# Parsing event sequence in R data frame

Tags: r, parsing, sequence

I have the following data frame of mouse actions:

```
Timestamp1, Timestamp2, button, state, x, y
49.8709998131,49.7949999999,NoButton,Move,498,580
49.8709998131,49.8730000001,Left,Pressed,498,580
49.9659998417,49.983,Left,Released,498,580
50.1739997864,50.1850000001,NoButton,Move,497,580
50.7269999981,50.7310000001,NoButton,Move,495,581
51.8219997883,51.7140000002,NoButton,Move,569,617
51.8229999542,51.8390000002,NoButton,Move,633,642
52.0539999008,51.8390000002,NoButton,Move,654,650
52.0539999008,51.9329999997,NoButton,Move,719,666
52.0539999008,52.057,NoButton,Move,761,666
52.1819999218,52.1979999999,NoButton,Move,763,663
52.5659999847,52.5720000002,NoButton,Move,763,659
52.6779999733,52.6809999999,NoButton,Move,778,658
52.893999815,52.6809999999,NoButton,Move,783,656
52.8949999809,52.8999999999,NoButton,Move,799,650
53.0549998283,53.0559999999,NoButton,Move,800,649
53.2349998951,53.2429999998,NoButton,Move,805,645
53.2349998951,53.2429999998,Left,Pressed,805,645
53.3509998322,53.2590000001,NoButton,Drag,807,644
53.3509998322,53.352,Left,Released,807,644
53.8619999886,53.8670000001,NoButton,Move,808,644
53.9739999771,53.9759999998,NoButton,Move,809,645
54.0779998302,54.085,NoButton,Move,802,686
54.1899998188,54.085,NoButton,Move,802,691
54.1909999847,54.1949999998,NoButton,Move,796,728
54.3019998074,54.304,NoButton,Move,795,745
54.4069998264,54.4130000002,NoButton,Move,796,756
54.5629999638,54.5529999998,NoButton,Move,801,766
54.751999855,54.7250000001,NoButton,Move,803,766
54.8379998207,54.8500000001,NoButton,Move,807,766
54.8389999866,54.8500000001,Left,Pressed,807,766
54.9709999561,54.9750000001,NoButton,Drag,808,766
54.9709999561,54.9750000001,Left,Released,808,766
55.3819999695,55.3960000002,NoButton,Move,809,766
55.5979998112,55.4890000001,NoButton,Move,801,760
55.5989999771,55.6140000001,NoButton,Move,790,752
```

I want to parse specific subsequences, like left click:

```
49.8709998131,49.8730000001,Left,Pressed,498,580
49.9659998417,49.983,Left,Released,498,580
```

or drag and drop, like:

```
53.2349998951,53.2429999998,Left,Pressed,805,645
53.3509998322,53.2590000001,NoButton,Drag,807,644
53.3509998322,53.352,Left,Released,807,644
```

or pure mouse movements uninterrupted by clicks like:

```
52.5659999847,52.5720000002,NoButton,Move,763,659
52.6779999733,52.6809999999,NoButton,Move,778,658
52.893999815,52.6809999999,NoButton,Move,783,656
52.8949999809,52.8999999999,NoButton,Move,799,650
53.0549998283,53.0559999999,NoButton,Move,800,649
53.2349998951,53.2429999998,NoButton,Move,805,645
```

My heuristic way is to iterate over the whole sequence with a for loop and examine each element before and after the actual element depending on the desired subsequence's specifics. That seems quite laborous on one hand, and doesn't fit to R's otherwise elegant apply-style short solutions on the other hand. Could anyone suggest more professional way?

---

I think I reiterate the problem in a more general way. Given the following data frame:

```
Timestamp, State1, x, y
50.1739997864,a,497,580
50.7269999981,a,495,581
51.8219997883,a,569,617
51.8229999542,b,633,642
52.0539999008,b,654,650
52.0539999008,a,719,666
52.0539999008,a,761,666
52.1819999218,b,763,663
52.5659999847,c,763,659
52.6779999733,b,778,658
52.893999815,a,783,656
52.8949999809,a,799,650
53.0549998283,b,800,649
53.2349998951,a,805,645
53.2349998951,b,805,645
53.3509998322,b,807,644
```

How could one get answers to the questions like:
- Which are the subsets with continuous State1=="a" rows?
- Which are the subsets with beginning and ending a row with    State1=="a" **and** at least one row with State1!="a" between them?
- What is the elapsed time/Euclidean distance of two neighbouring rows     where in the first case State1!="a" and in the second case       State1=="b"?

Comment: Would be nice to know more specifically what your desired output would be. Do you want a vector of strings that says "move, left click, move, drag drop, move, drag drop, move"?

Comment: First read in your data with `read.csv` so you can subset. It may be worth adding an index column (`df$id <- seq_along(df$Timestamp1)`) so you can tell if events follow each other; `data.table::rleid` may be helpful, too. Really, though, it's hard to give you a good answer without you telling us what it should look like.

Comment: You might find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027611/how-to-index-a-vector-sequence-within-a-vector-sequence) helpful. Using any of the functions there -say `FUN`- like `intersect(FUN(c("Left", "NoButton", "Left"), as.character(DF$button)), FUN(c("Pressed", "Drag", "Released"), as.character(DF$state)))` will give the starting row positions of your specific pattern.

Comment: My goal is to get different characteristics of different kind of mouse activities: elapsed times and direction angles between _"pure" movements_ (sequences without any button pressing; this is why I need to parse only movements), _clicks_ (with press-release sequences without any movement between them), _drag-and-drops_ (press-at least one movement while pressed-release) and so on. The task is a bit challenging for me; I am unsure whether to cut up the whole data frame to more appropriate subsequences and computate on these after, or leave the sequence intact...

Answer (score 0):

Looping would work, but might be slow. There is a faster approach, for example

```
df$state[-nrow(df)] == "Left,Pressed" &  df$state[-1] == "Left,Released"
```

This makes a logical vector showing the position of "left,pressed" that where immediately followed by a "left,released"

Similar code would work for the drag and drop. For the mouse movement, `rle()` might be useful.