# Identify instances of a pattern in a character vector in R

Tags: r, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I'm trying to identify all instances of a pattern in a vector of strings. I'm looking at something like this:

```
    fruits <- c("Cherry", "Grape", "Orange", "Lemon")
    pattern <- c("Lemon", "Grape", "Cherry", "Grape")
    full <- sample(fruits, 1000, replace = TRUE)
```

I just want to find every instance of `pattern` in `full`. My inner Java baby says to loop, something like this maybe?

```
    for(i in 1:(length(full)-length(pattern))) {
      if(full[i] == pattern[1]) {
        if(full[i+1] == pattern[2]) {
          ...
```

And then save the indices. But that doesn't seem very R or very efficient to me. Is this the way to go, or can someone point me in the direction of a function or package that could make this easier/quicker?

edit:
Sorry I'm not being clear, I need to know where `pattern` starts in `full`, i.e. if somewhere in `full` ends up looking  something like this:

```
    ...
    [177] "Lemon"  "Grape " "Cherry" "Grape"  "Grape"  "Lemon"  "Cherry" "Grape"  "Lemon"  "Cherry" "Orange"
    ...
```

Then I'd have a way to find that index (177) since the pattern (Lemon, Grape, Cherry, Grape) appears there and starts there. Then ideally if the pattern reappeared later I'd know that too, I need to be able to find *all instances* of `pattern`.

Comment: I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027611/how-to-index-a-vector-sequence-within-a-vector-sequence) should be similar

Comment: Actually maybe disregard the edit I think you got me covered here.

Answer (score 3):

The following should work .

```
which(full %in% pattern)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear to me what you're looking for but

```
l = apply(sapply(full, grepl, pattern), 1, function(x) { (1:length(full))[x] })
names(l) = pattern
```

Will give you a list of the same length as elements in `pattern`, indexing where in `full` that `pattern` is seen.  I'm using `grepl`, because `pattern` implies string matching to me, which could be

If it's not partial string matching, `%in%` will definitely be faster.