# R - Subset dataframe based on a repeated sequence

Tags: r, sequence, subset

I am trying to subset a data frame based on specific sequence occurring in column `v3`. 
A sample of a dataframe:

```
v1 <- c(1:20)
v2 <- c(1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0)
v3 <- c(4,4,2,3,2,3,2,4,4,2,3,2,3,3,3,4,4,2,3,3)
my_df <- data.frame(v1,v2,v3)         # creating a dataframe
```

sample output for `my_df`

```
   v1 v2 v3
1   1  1  4
2   2  1  4
3   3  0  2
4   4  0  3
5   5  1  2
6   6  0  3
7   7  1  2
8   8  1  4
9   9  1  4
10 10  0  2
11 11  1  3
12 12  1  2
13 13  0  3
14 14  0  3
15 15  0  3
16 16  1  4
17 17  1  4
18 18  0  2
19 19  0  3
20 20  0  3
```

The output I am trying to achieve should look like this

```
1   1  1  4
2   2  1  4
3   3  0  2
8   8  1  4
9   9  1  4
10 10  0  2
16 16  1  4
17 17  1  4
18 18  0  2
```

So I want to subset my df according to sequence of `4 4 2` in column `v3`. What I tried so far is:

```
my_df[which(c(diff(v3))==-2),]
```

but this only extracts the middle four of the sequence `4 4 2` like

```
v1 v2 v3
 2  2  1  4
 9  9  1  4
17 17  1  4
```

Another option I tried:

```
m = match(v3, c(4,4,2))
> m
 [1]  1  1  3 NA  3 NA  3  1  1  3 NA  3 NA NA NA  1  1  3 NA NA  
> my_df[!is.na(m),]
   v1 v2 v3
1   1  1  4
2   2  1  4
3   3  0  2
5   5  1  2
7   7  1  2
8   8  1  4
9   9  1  4
10 10  0  2
12 12  1  2
16 16  1  4
17 17  1  4
18 18  0  2
```

This output gives me all 4 and 2 but not the sequence `4 4 2` that I want. Any help would be appreciated.
I already achieved this in matlab with for and if loop but I am just wondering how I can solve this in R in a loopless way.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027611/how-to-index-a-vector-sequence-within-a-vector-sequence) a similar question on finding a sequence in a numeric vector. All answers there output a vector of indices of where a match occurs (here, `c(1, 8, 16)`) which you can use to subset your `my_df`. I.e. assuming `i = c(1, 8, 16)`, then `c(outer(0:2, i, "+"))` gives all indices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(my_df)`).  Using `shift` from `data.table`, we get the next element with `type = "lead"`.  As `shift` takes a vector of `n`, we specify `n = 0:2`, so that we get three columns with the `n = 0` corresponds to the original 'v3' column and others 1st and 2nd next values.  Then, `paste` the elements rowwise (`do.call(paste0, ...`), check whether it is equal to 442, get the index of TRUE values (`which`), use `rep` to replicate the index and add with 0:2 so that we get the index of the three rows for each index.  This can be used to subset the original dataset rows.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(my_df)[my_df[, rep(which(do.call(paste0, shift(v3, 0:2,
                 type= "lead")) == 442), each = 3) + 0:2]]
#   v1 v2 v3
#1:  1  1  4
#2:  2  1  4
#3:  3  0  2
#4:  8  1  4
#5:  9  1  4
#6: 10  0  2
#7: 16  1  4
#8: 17  1  4
#9: 18  0  2
```

#### data

```
my_df <- structure(list(v1 = 1:20, v2 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), v3 = c(4L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 3L)), .Names = c("v1", "v2", "v3"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"))
```

Comment: One question, applying your technique on the output sequence now I am trying to count the 110 and 111 from v2. `which(do.call(paste0, shift(seq$v2, 0:2, type= "lead")) == 110)
[1] 7` so I know that there is only one 110 sequence, but it doesn't work same for the 111 `which(do.call(paste0, shift(seq$v2, 0:2, type= "lead")) == 111)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6` it gives all the indices. Updated v2 `v2 <- c(1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0)`

Comment: @Amgh Your example doesn't have 111.

Comment: Yes, I updated v2 for further analysis `v1 <- c(1:20) 
>  v2 <- c(1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0) 
>  v3 <- c(4,4,2,3,2,3,2,4,4,2,3,2,3,3,3,4,4,2,3,3) 
>   my_df <- data.frame(v1,v2,v3)         # creating a datafram`

Comment: @Amgh I get `setDT(my_df)[, which(do.call(paste0, shift(v3, 0:2, type= "lead")) == 111)]
#integer(0)`

Comment: we get the output of this updated dataframe like `seq <- setDT(my_df)[my_df[, rep(which(do.call(paste0, shift(v3, 0:2, type= "lead")) == 442), each = 3) + 0:2]]` and now I did apply `which(do.call(paste0, shift(seq$v2, 0:2, type= "lead")) == 111)`  output is ´[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6´ but if I do `which(do.call(paste0, shift(seq$v2, 0:2, type= "lead")) == 110)` then output is `[1] 7`

Comment: @Amgh Can you update your post with a new example as the example and the output is not matching.

Answer (score 2):

As long as v3 does not have any missing values and the values of v3 are single characters, you can also use `gregexpr` to accomplish this as follows

```
# get the row indices where the pattern 442 starts c(1 , 8, 16)
rowstarts <- unlist(gregexpr("442", paste(my_df$v3, collapse="")))

# extract rows from the data fram
dfNew <- my_df[sort(c(outer(rowstarts, (0:2), "+"))), ]
```

which returns

```
dfNew
   v1 v2 v3
1   1  1  4
2   2  1  4
3   3  0  2
8   8  1  4
9   9  1  4
10 10  0  2
16 16  1  4
17 17  1  4
18 18  0  2
```

`paste` with the collapse argument turns the vector v3 into a single character string. `grexpr` then finds the starting position in this string for any "442" subexpression.

The final step subsets the data.frame using the `outer` function suggested by @alexis-laz's in the comments above.