# Find the indices of changes in a vector of characters in R

Tags: r

I have a vector with two types of characters as below.

```
dat <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 2), rep("A", 5), rep("B", 4), rep("A", 8))
```

which contains "A" and "B". I want to find all indices when "A" -> "B" and "B" -> "A".

For example,

```
> dat
[1] "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "B" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A"
```

I want to calculate two numeric vectors: A2B should be (3, 10) and B2A should be (5, 14).

Comment: Try `which(c(dat[-1]!= dat[-length(dat)], FALSE))`

Comment: Also `tmp <- paste(dat, collapse = "") ; gregexpr("AB", tmp) ; gregexpr("BA", tmp)`

Comment: For a more general case, you might find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027611/how-to-index-a-vector-sequence-within-a-vector-sequence) helpful. Passing "dat" and (i) `c("A", "B")`, (ii) `c("B", "A")` as arguments (vector and pattern, respectively) to any of the functions there and `union` the result should give the wanted output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
diffs <- diff(as.integer(as.factor(dat))) 
A2B <- which(diffs == 1L)
B2A <- which(diffs == - 1L)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a run-length encoding representation of your data

```
r = rle(dat)
```

Then extract the cumulative index of the trailing transition

```
cumsum(r$lengths)[which(r$value == "B") - 1L]   # A2B        
cumsum(r$lengths)[which(r$value == "A") - 1L]   # B2A
```