# Find the index of changes in a vector of characters in R

Tags: r, dataframe

My question is similar to the one I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41612904/find-the-indices-of-changes-in-a-vector-of-characters-in-r) but I can't adapt the answers to my case.

Consider this data frame

```
x = seq(0, 1.4, by = 0.1)
z = c("n", "n", "b", "b", "b", "n", "n", "b", "b", "b", "b", "m", "m", "m", "m")
df = data.frame(x, z)
```

We would like to find the **last** `x` where we switch from `n` to `b` and the **first** `x` where we switch from `b` to `m`.

Could someone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make two variables that identify the cases you're interested in.  Switching from `n` to `b` happens when `z == "b"` and `lag(z) == "n"`.  You can define switching from `b` to `m` similarly.  Then you can just filter the data to identify the two cases you want to see.

```r
library(dplyr)
x = seq(0, 1.4, by = 0.1)
z = c("n", "n", "b", "b", "b", "n", "n", "b", "b", "b", "b", "m", "m", "m", "m")
df = data.frame(x, z)

df %>% mutate(n_to_b = ifelse(z == "b" & lag(z) == "n", 1, 0), 
              b_to_m = ifelse(z == "m" & lag(z) == "b", 1, 0)) %>% 
  filter(row_number() == max(which(n_to_b == 1)) | 
         row_number() == min(which(b_to_m == 1)))
#>     x z n_to_b b_to_m
#> 1 0.7 b      1      0
#> 2 1.1 m      0      1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We can find concatenate all rows in the `z` column into a single string, then use `gregexpr` to locate the string positions of "nb" and "bm". Then use the string location to index the original `df`.

Use `nb + 1` and `bm + 1` if you wish to find the corresponding `x` value from the "b" row for example in `nb`.

```r
nb <- max(gregexpr("nb", paste0(df[, "z"], collapse = ""))[[1]])
bm <- min(gregexpr("bm", paste0(df[, "z"], collapse = ""))[[1]])

df[c(nb, bm),]
     x z
7  0.6 n
11 1.0 b
```