# Match a vector to multiple consecutive rows in R

Tags: r, match, row, col

I have got a dataframe and I need to find row numbers where the values of the entries in one column match a certain pattern.

Let the col1 `col1 = matrix(c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1), nrow = 21, ncol = 1)` be an example of by column and vector r `r = c(2, 0 ,2)` be a vector I need to match it with.

I need R to return an index number of rows where the pattern in r matches the values in col1 (in this case row 11, 12, 13).

I thought I could achieve this with row.match, but that is not the case. I have tried different combinations of match function, but it doesn't yield any results either.

Maybe the way I am approaching this problem is wrong from the beginning, but I have trouble believing that there isn't any function, that would provide me with the expected result given some adjustment.

Thanks.

Comment: It would seem you're having problem with the algorithm. How would you approach this _on paper_? One way of doing this would be to convert your column into a string, find your match and return match indices.

Comment: I think this has been pretty comprehensively thrashed out here - [How to index a vector sequence within a vector sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027611/how-to-index-a-vector-sequence-within-a-vector-sequence/33028695) - `find_pat(r, col1)` from the accepted answer returns `11`

Comment: Thanks for reply guys. Yes, the custom find_pat function seems to solve it for me, thanks a lot, thelatemail!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this using `rollapply` from `zoo`. Basically, this runs `identical` on a rolling basis with a window of `length(r)`. This tells you that the sequence is present starting at positon 11 of the `col1` vector..

```
library(zoo)
which(rollapply(col1,length(r),identical,r))
[1] 11
```

To get a vector of positions, you could do:

```
which(rollapply(col1,length(r),identical,r))+0:(length(r)-1)
[1] 11 12 13
```

Comment: Thanks, Pierre, it is clever and helpful. Runs nicely with my example, but for whatever reason outputs empty integer with my actual data. But I think it is the right way to do that, and hopefully, I can solve it tomorrow.

Comment: @ayasugihada Make sure the data is the same type `typeof(col1)` and `typeof(r)`

Comment: Yes, I thought the problem will be with the column, but it was in fact with the vector. Now it works flawlessly.