# How to check if a vector or dataframe has a specific order of specific values?

Tags: r

Let's say we have three vectors:

```r
vec1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
vec2 = c(1, 4, 3, 1, 2)
vec3 = c(5, 5, 4, 2, 1)
```

And let's say I am interested in this specific order of these specific values:

```r
specific_order_of_specific_values <- c(1, 2)
```

**How do I find the vectors which contain that specific order of specific values?**

In our example, `vec1` and `vec2` would return as TRUE and `vec3` would return as FALSE.

---

My idea to solve this is to write a function that loops through each index of the vector and checks if that index matches the first index of the "matching vector." If it does, then check if the i + 1 index matches the the second index of the "matching vector." And so on, so forth. I am genuinely curious if there is a more elegant solution to this using base functions, etc.

---

**P.S.** My actual problem is slightly more complicated since I am interested in which rows (of a matrix) have a very specific order of values. But I can simply convert the data frame to a list of vectors.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Should I reword the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027611/how-to-index-a-vector-sequence-within-a-vector-sequence/33028695 - which has some very fast and pretty thoroughly tested solutions for indexing a vector within another vector.

Comment: E.g. - `lapply(list(vec1,vec2,vec3), find_pat, pat=specific_order_of_specific_values)` gives you the matching indexes in each list of your specific values.

Comment: what is find_pat?

Comment: The function in the accepted answer to the question I linked above.

Comment: `grepl(paste(specific_order_of_specific_values,collapse = ""),do.call(paste0,data.frame(rbind(vec1,vec2,vec3))))`

Answer (score 2):

This is neither the prettiest nor most efficient way to go about it, but I think captures the logic:

```
has_subvec = function(x,s){
  xL = length(x); sL = length(s)
  if(xL < sL) return(FALSE)
  any(sapply(1:(xL-sL+1),function(i){
    isTRUE(all.equal(x[i:(i+sL-1)],s))
  }))
}
```

where `x` is the vector to search within and `s` is the 'subvector' we're looking for.

To search each row of a matrix, can use `apply(M,1,has_subvec,s=c(1,2))`.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing a function that solves this problem for a list of vectors. This is a pretty ugly solution, so I encourage corrections to mine or more elegant alternative solutions.

```r
matching_vector_test <- c(1033, 280)

test_list <- list(c(1033, 280, 112), c(1033, 112, 280))

match_vector <- function(list_of_vectors, matching_vector) {

  list_of_matching_vectors <- list()

for (i in 1:length(list_of_vectors)) {
  for (j in 1:length(list_of_vectors[[i]])) {
    for (k in 1:length(matching_vector)) {
    if ((k < length(matching_vector)) & (j < length(list_of_vectors[[i]])) & (list_of_vectors[[i]][j] == matching_vector[k]) & (list_of_vectors[[i]][j+1] == matching_vector[k + 1])) {
      print("test")
      list_of_matching_vectors[[i]] <- list_of_vectors[[i]]
      break
        }
      }
    }
  }


  list_of_matching_vectors <- Filter(length, list_of_matching_vectors)
  list_of_matching_vectors
}

match_vector(list_of_vectors = test_list, matching_vector = matching_vector_test )

[[1]]
[1] 1033  280  112
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to convert the vector and pattern to match to string and use `grepl` to know if the pattern exists in other vectors.

```
order_match <- toString(c(1, 2))
grepl(paste0("\\b", order_match,"\\b"), sapply(list(vec1, vec2, vec3), toString))
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```